# How to get file extension in Marklogic Server?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I want to get the file extension of uploaded file in Marklogic server. I know how to get the file name. But that gives filename plus extension like new.txt. But I want only extension not the full file name. How can I get just the file extension ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many methods of getting file extensions from filename. For instance you can use `functx:substring-after-last($filename, '.')` or other methods `(fn:substring-after)` of getting substring after dot. Please see: [xqueryfunctions.com](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/c0008.html#c0046)

P.S. `fn:tokenize($filename, '\.')[fn:last()]`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `fn:tokenize($filename, '\.')[fn:last()]`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The second parameter takes regular expression pattern. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it works as you said, using let $uriExtension := fn:tokenize($baseURI, '\.')[fn:last()]

Answer (score 1):

I often use the following replace:

```
fn:replace("c:\a\b\c.d.e.txt", '^(.*\.)?([^\.]+)$', '$2')
```

But using functx is a good idea too, as suggested by Andrew. A copy of the functx library is distributed as part of the latter versions of MarkLogic. Just add the following import to get them available:

```
import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com" at "/MarkLogic/functx/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xqy";
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Just for variety, yet another expression that produces the extension :)  :

```
reversed-string(substring-before(reversed-string($filePath), '.'))
```

where `reversed-string($s)` can be defined as:

```
codepoints-to-string(reverse(string-to-code-points($s)))
```

So the whole expression with the substitution is:

```
codepoints-to-string(
             reverse(
              string-to-codepoints(
               substring-before(codepoints-to-string(reverse(string-to-codepoints($filePath))),
                               '.')
                                   )
                     )
                              )
```