# Xquery Multiple file upload

Tags: html, xquery, marklogic

My single file upload looks like this:

```
declare function local:uploadFile()
{

let $file := xdmp:get-request-field("upload")
let $filename := xdmp:get-request-field-filename("upload")
let $contenttype := xdmp:get-request-field-content-type("upload")
let $extension := fn:replace($filename, '.*\.', '')
let $insert := switch ($contenttype)
    case "text/xml"
    case "text/xhtml"
    case "text/csv"
    case "text/plain"
    case "application/json"
        return xdmp:document-insert($filename,xdmp:unquote($file))
    case "application/octet-stream"
        return switch ($extension)
        case "gpx"
            return xdmp:document-insert($filename,xdmp:unquote(xdmp:quote(binary{xs:hexBinary($file)})))
        default
            return xdmp:document-insert($filename,$file)
    default
        return xdmp:document-insert($filename,$file)
return fn:concat("file '",$filename,"' uploaded, contenttype: ",$contenttype," extension: ",$extension)
};
```

And now I want to change this to support multiple files.
The html form it uses, supports the uploading of multiple files by adding the `multiple="true"` attribute.

And it looks like this:

```
<form name="test" action="upload.xqy" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><label>File to upload:
    <input type="file" class="name" name="upload" size="50" multiple="true" /></label></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload and Get Results"/></p>
    </form>
```

Problem is that if I try to upload multiple files, the `get-request-field(`) statements give back multiple arguments. I tried using `fn:tokenize()` but that does not work. Is there something like a for-loop I can use or is there a function to break them up?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, xdmp:get-request-field() function signature states that it returns item*  - Therefore, you can expect that it is returning a sequence of items and can be accessed via `xdmp:get-request-field()[1]`, `xdmp:get-request-field()[2]` etc.. etc..

Likely you would consider doing this this in a FLWOR statement balancing the same request-field with request-filename(also the same signature and in the same order)

Wondering why you can consider it a scalar originally? xQuery conveniently considers a sequence of one item and a scalar as the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Executing a loop across a set of functions returning matching sequences can be tricky for an xquery novice.  There are lots of ways to do it.  Here is a simple one:

```
  for $file at $pos in xdmp:get-request-field("upload")
    let $filename := xdmp:get-request-field-filename("upload")[$pos],
      $contenttype := xdmp:get-request-field-content-type("upload")[$pos],
      $extension := fn:replace($filename, '.*\.', ''),
      $insert := switch ($contenttype)
   ...
```

NOTE  use of $pos to extract the position from the first sequence only, then using it to extract the correct item from each of the other requests.

NOTE: Use of an alternate let style (personal preference, I prefer to not see the let's repeated each line)

You can do this other ways, for example see the reference implementation of fn:for-each-pair in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-for-each-pair

For alternatives to getting the file extension see [How to get file extension in Marklogic Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290464/how-to-get-file-extension-in-marklogic-server)